# sql how to empty a table after a merge statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is my stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sync_vmp

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    merge into FRM_DTA as Target
    using FRM_DTA_VMP as Source
    on Target.FRM_ID = Source.FRM_ID
    when matched then
    update set
    target.FRM_OWNER = Source.FRM_OWNER,
    target.FRM_OWNER_AR = Source.FRM_OWNER_AR,
    target.FRM_OWNER_EN = Source.FRM_OWNER_EN,
    target.FRM_AREA_ID = Source.FRM_AREA_ID,
    target.FRM_AREA = Source.FRM_AREA,
    target.FRM_AREA_AR = Source.FRM_AREA_AR,
    target.FRM_EMARA_ID = Source.FRM_EMARA_ID,
    target.FRM_EMARA = Source.FRM_EMARA,
    target.FRM_EMARA_AR = Source.FRM_EMARA_AR,
    target.FRM_REGION_ID = Source.FRM_REGION_ID,
    target.FRM_REGION = Source.FRM_REGION,
    target.FRM_REGION_AR = Source.FRM_REGION_AR,
    target.RecievingCentreID = Source.RecievingCentreID,
    target.RecievingCentreAr = Source.RecievingCentreAr,
    target.RecievingCentre = Source.RecievingCentre,
    target.Owner_Address = Source.Owner_Address,
    target.Owner_Address_Ar = Source.Owner_Address_Ar,
    target.FRM_TELEPHONE = Source.FRM_TELEPHONE,
    target.FRM_MOBILE = Source.FRM_MOBILE,
    target.Owner_BankName_ID = Source.Owner_BankName_ID,
    target.Owner_BankName = Source.Owner_BankName,
    target.Owner_BankBranch_ID = Source.Owner_BankBranch_ID,
    target.Owner_BankBranch = Source.Owner_BankBranch,
    target.BankAccountNo = Source.BankAccountNo,
    target.AccountActive = Source.AccountActive,
    target.PrefPaymentMethod = Source.PrefPaymentMethod,
    target.FRM_CAT = Source.FRM_CAT,
    target.farmNumber = Source.farmNumber,
    target.FRM_PASSPORT = Source.FRM_PASSPORT,
    target.FRM_Approve = Source.FRM_Approve,
    target.FRM_AUDIT_STATUS = Source.FRM_AUDIT_STATUS,
    target.FRM_AUDIT_REASON = Source.FRM_AUDIT_REASON,
    target.FRM_WATER_SAL = Source.FRM_WATER_SAL,
    target.FRM_SOL_SAL = Source.FRM_SOL_SAL,
    target.syn_status = Source.syn_status,
    target.FRM_status = Source.FRM_status,
    target.Call_status = Source.Call_status,
    target.ALZAKA_CH = Source.ALZAKA_CH
    when not matched then
    insert(FRM_ID,FRM_OWNER,FRM_OWNER_AR,FRM_AREA_ID,FRM_AREA,FRM_AREA_AR,FRM_EMARA_ID,FRM_EMARA,FRM_EMARA_AR,FRM_REGION_ID,FRM_REGION,FRM_REGION_AR,RecievingCentreID,RecievingCentreAr,RecievingCentre,Owner_Address,Owner_Address_Ar,FRM_TELEPHONE,FRM_MOBILE,Owner_BankName_ID,Owner_BankName,Owner_BankBranch_ID,Owner_BankBranch,BankAccountNo,AccountActive,PrefPaymentMethod,FRM_CAT,farmNumber,FRM_PASSPORT,FRM_Approve,FRM_AUDIT_STATUS,FRM_AUDIT_REASON,FRM_WATER_SAL,FRM_SOL_SAL,syn_status,FRM_status,Call_status,ALZAKA_CH)
    values (Source.FRM_ID,Source.FRM_OWNER, Source.FRM_OWNER_AR,Source.FRM_AREA_ID,Source.FRM_AREA,Source.FRM_AREA_AR,Source.FRM_EMARA_ID,Source.FRM_EMARA,Source.FRM_EMARA_AR,Source.FRM_REGION_ID,Source.FRM_REGION,Source.FRM_REGION_AR,Source.RecievingCentreID,Source.RecievingCentreAr,Source.RecievingCentre,Source.Owner_Address,Source.Owner_Address_Ar,Source.FRM_TELEPHONE,Source.FRM_MOBILE,Source.Owner_BankName_ID,Source.Owner_BankName,Source.Owner_BankBranch_ID,Source.Owner_BankBranch,Source.BankAccountNo,Source.AccountActive,Source.PrefPaymentMethod,Source.FRM_CAT,Source.farmNumber,Source.FRM_PASSPORT,Source.FRM_Approve,Source.FRM_AUDIT_STATUS,Source.FRM_AUDIT_REASON,Source.FRM_WATER_SAL,Source.FRM_SOL_SAL,Source.syn_status,Source.FRM_status,Source.Call_status,Source.ALZAKA_CH);

END
```

as you see, I am merging data from dbo.FRM_DTA_VMP to dbo.FRM_DTA

my question is how to empty the dbo.FRM_DTA_VMP after this stored procedure execute?

**I want to do that just if no exception happened in the merge**

Comment: truncate table dbo.FRM_DTA_VMP?

Comment: Cant you Truncate the Table after SP execution?

Comment: @Robert I know I can delete myself and one of the ways is the truncate but I am asking about if merge statement comes with something in default because it is a giving when a user merge, he/she wants to delete the source table. got me please?

Comment: @JithinShaji the same comment that I wrote to Robert, read it please. I am asking about if there is no exceptions. if there is a standard way to deal with delete and merge

Comment: Use [Transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174377.aspx)

Comment: @bansi could you give me an answer with that please?

Comment: In Merge, we can DELETE as well
Like  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN DELETE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AS people mention you can truncate the table in the sproc right after the `MERGE` statement. Check for errors with the `@@ERROR` variable like this;
To clarify:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedure
BEGIN
--code goes here

 IF @@ERROR = 0 --no errors
   BEGIN
    TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.FRM_DTA_VMP
   END
END
```

MSDN: [@ERROR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188790.aspx)

Comment: should I put your code **right before** the `End`word? of after it please?

Comment: Oh sorry, the `THEN` shouldn't be there

Comment: You can't just `TRUNCATE` any old table. There are limitations.